# Why is there no option to use Paypal?

Tags: elementary-website

all. I'd like to know why I can't pay for elementary with Paypal. Also, if I enter $0, can I just download the image file?

Comment: Elementary is using Stripe, a Paypal competitor, so you can't "pay via Paypal".

Comment: There's Stripe again- should I be concerned?

Comment: What do you mean with "should I be concerned"?

Comment: I was also referred to Reedsy, a writing service that _only_ accepts payment via Stripe.

Comment: Ah, that's what you're referring to. I'm not sure if using Stripe will take away the business/organization's rights on using Paypal or the other way around. But I haven't heard of anything that accepts both. *\*blurts out my hate for anti-comptetitive practices by large corporations\**

Answer (score 2):

you can enter $0 and download elementary.

Comment: Thank you. I've downloaded it, but haven't done anything with it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that PayPal would raise more money as it is a more common method of payment that many have when, for instance. acting on eBay. If Elementary team offered payment by PayPal also I am sure that they could obtain more payments immediately .. However, it is their own geeky choice